# Sorting letter occurrences in a text alphabetically

Tags: python, sorting

I need to present the occurrences of letters in a text. If one of the letters doesn't occur, it should show zero and also output should be sorted alphabetically. I have prepared the following Python code, my questions are how can I show zero for non-occurring letters and how can I sort the list values based on the list keys to sort my output?

```
 fdist = Counter(c for c in f.lower() if c.isalpha())
 print sorted(fdist.items()) #only to show the output details
 print fdist.values()
```

the output for a sample text is like this:

```
[('a', 46), ('b', 5), ('c', 11), ('d', 22), ('e', 76), ('f', 13), ('g', 7), ('h', 29), ('i', 30), ('j', 1), ('k', 6), ('l', 21), ('m', 11), ('n', 34), ('o', 31), ('p', 6), ('q', 1), ('r', 24), ('s', 32), ('t', 52), ('u', 7), ('v', 2), ('w', 10), ('y', 11)]

[46, 11, 5, 76, 22, 7, 13, 30, 29, 6, 1, 11, 21, 31, 34, 1, 6, 32, 24, 7, 52, 10, 2, 11]
```

but the output should look like this:

```
[46, 5, 11, 22, 76, 13, 7, 29, 46, 1, 6, 21, 11, 34, 31, 6, 1, 24, 32, 52, 7, 2, 10, 0, 11, 0]
```

Comment: To get the zero elements you might use something like: fdist(string.lower); for i in fdisk.keys(): fdist[i] -=1  (setting them all to 1 using the "string.lower" data from the "string" module; then zero-ing them all back out before you use the fdist counter for your actual computations.  If you only want the values but sorted by the letters you can use print [fdist[k] for k in sorted(fdist.keys()]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this (ignoring the sorting part for now) ?

```
import string

result = [fdist.get(l, 0) for l in string.letters]
```

or

```
result = [fdist.get(l, 0) for l in string.ascii_lowercase]
```

since you're only dealing with lowercase characters

Comment: Since `string.ascii_lowercase` is already sorted, your're basically not *ignoring the sorting part for now* and `result` is already the required output.

Comment: @astrognocci Thank you. your second solution solved my both problems.

Answer (score 1):

Note @astrognocci answer is simpler and more elegant, but this will also work.

Create the counter with the keys of the alphabet (but set to zero initially)

```
import string
fdist = Counter([f for f in string.ascii_lowercase])
for c in string.ascii_lowercase:
    fdist[c] = 0
```

The `sorted(fdist.items())` returns a sorted list, it doesn't sort the items in place. You can create a copy of the sorted list, and then use the sorted list as below;

```
 x = sorted(fdist.items())
 print x.values()
```

Or you could sort the list `fdist` in place;

```
 fdist.items().sort()
 print fdist.values()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!python
import string
from collections import Counter

fdist = Counter(string.lowercase)
for k in fdist.keys():
    fdist[k] = 0 

# process your data:
for c in f:
    if c.isalpha():
        fdist.update(c.lower())

# print it
print [fdist[k] for k in sorted(fdist.keys())]
```

Answer (score 0):

The output does not include zero items. Maybe you should look at the `Counter` function again so that it generates the items for which the count is zero; then implementing @danodonovan's solution will be enough.

```
from string import ascii.lowercase as letters

fdist = [(letter, 0) for letter in letters]
```

then update as necessary and print the sorted list with

```
result = [entry[1] for entry in fdist]
```

This should be enough to put the right values in `result`.